# How to set date/time in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there is a way to get the date/time from SQL using:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
GO
```

but is there a way to set the date/time of the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear:  You want to set the server's date and time by using TSQL?  Is there any particular reason you're trying to take this approach?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables  Yes, I want to call this from a C# application so that I can be sure that the database's time is the same as the time on the VM.

Comment: The time reported by `GETDATE()` is the time the underlying machine has... if you want to change that - change the system time for the machine....

Comment: The database's time *is already* the same as the time of the machine it is running on. Now, if you're talking about keeping two *different* machines in sync, that's a different issue, but still has nothing to do with the database or the SQL Server instance.

Comment: You could probably do something dumb like call xp_cmdshell and then use the DOS `date` and `time` passing in the desired values. Whether that's a good idea, I leave entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the date and time of the SQL `GETDATE()` function then you can do one of the following:

- Change the date and time of the server where your SQL Server instance is installed.
- Change the timezone setting of the server where your SQL Server instance is installed..

Comment: How do you do this - 'you can also do it by setting timezone of the server' ?

Comment: Take server remote and from bottom right cornet click on date open calendar , from there you change time or set timezone.

Comment: Dowvoted...please add code.

Comment: Read my ans. Do you think that can be converted into code?

Comment: Upvote for you, it can't be convert into code .

Answer (score 0):

You can set time/date on the machine where the server is running...

Comment: That was my first thought, is it true?

Comment: @Mowgli please elaborate. Is what true?

Comment: What he answered, if you change time on the server which SQL is running on.

Comment: The server gets its date from the machine on which it's running. Think about what would happen to all scheduled jobs if any user could change server time at will...

Comment: @Mowgli yes, as has been stated several times on this very page, SQL Server gets its time from the underlying operating system. It doesn't have its own clock.