# Facing issue when saving date time using datetime picker in vb.net winforms

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have table with column datatype datetime and i want to save date time from the datetime picker.But the result i am getting is **`2021-01-03 16:05:15.000`** however the time on machine is different.when i use **`GETDATE()`** function the output is **`2020-02-03 16:05:59.637`**.

All i want is to have a single format across the application whether date time taken from datetime picker or use **`getdate()`** in `SQL`.

Yes there is need of time format along with date.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a format. Don't try to *format* what you insert into a database (you have a DateTime column there, right?), format what comes out of it, for presentation purposes.

Comment: Do you click on the DateTimePicker first? How did you make its date **January** 3rd, **2021**?

Answer (score 0):

The [datepicker app] will use the format/regional-settings of the machine/host running your app. Getdate() will return format/regional-settings of the [sql host/server].
Are these different hosts/machines or is your [sql server] and [datepicker App] running on the same host/machine?

This might help.
[How to set date/time in SQL Server Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555131/how-to-set-date-time-in-sql-server-database)